# UITableView: automatically set height for the row and fix it with max height constant

Tags: swift, height, row, tableview, cell

I need automatically set the height for the row. I use

```
theTable.estimatedRowHeight = 60
theTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

but the height is not fixed. I need fixed height something like **MAX** 60 height, by default height is 40. With estimatedRowHeight the height is not fixed and when the string is long the cell takes all screen. How to fix it?

Comment: try cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2 // which you want

Comment: xaxa now it works but I have to set 10 lines :D
I'm waiting for the answer... if there is an answer.. :D

Comment: then set cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 10

Comment: and when lines are set I have space between label and cell which cannot be removed..

Comment: you check it work or not

Comment: in my case also, but I told u that I have empty space between label and separator with your method.. I need to set maxHeight for the row, but I don't know how to do it...

Comment: set tableview and cell row height value same in storyboard i hope it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to put all the content of table view cell in a single view (lets call it MainView) and set MainView top, leading and trailing edge constrains to container view. Also set a height constraint less than or equal to 60 with required priority. After that put your label in MainView set top, leading and trailing constrains to MainView and a bottom space to MainView constraint with high priority. Also on your label set number of lines to 0 and preferred width to explicit. This way if label content height is less than 60, MainView will shrink and that will still match height constraint of less than or equal to 60. Otherwise if content height is greater then 60 the bottom space to MainView constraint will break without causing problems since its priority is less then MainView height constraint.

Finally override tableview delegate methods as follow

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
```